# Confused About DocumentDB Pricing

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I see that in [Microsoft Azure Website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/documentdb/), pricing for DocumentDB is based on collections. For example, for a 1GB Storage and 100 RU, something about (~£4/mo) is billed for me.

The description is:

> At any scale, you can store data and provision throughput capacity.
>   Each collection is billed hourly based on the amount of data stored
>   (in GBs) and throughput reserved in units of 100 RUs/second.

My confusion is this: Is it really billing me for each collection I have? If my application uses a database with 20 collections in it, should I pay (~£80/mo)? Or by collection it means a database?

Thank you all

Comment: Yes, DocumentDB bills per collection. It helps to think of collections as equivalent to (relational) databases. You provision throughput per collection, run queries against a collection, and store multiple types within a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. You will have to pay for each collection as the throughput is defined per collection. So in your example you'll pay £80 for 20 collections (or £4 per collection).

Answer (score 1):

A collection in Document DB can be considered equivalent to a table in normal database terms. It isn't equivalent to a database.

Comment: This is wrong. A collection should be regarded more on level - at least in terms of what you store into it - with a relational database, as you typically would store most of your data (yes, different types of data, as its schema agnostic) in ONE collection, to keep prices down. You would use the partition key to group by entity or something else that feels appropriate to your system.

If it were like you suggested (similar to a relational table), the prices for a typical ecommerce system of 70+ tables would be insane.

Comment: I don't follow why you think the answer is wrong.  Here is the glossary definition from MongoDB: A grouping of MongoDB documents. A collection is the equivalent of an RDBMS table. A collection exists within a single database. Collections do not enforce a schema. Documents within a collection can have different fields. Typically, all documents in a collection have a similar or related purpose.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. In a typical relational application, one would have a database with X numbers of tables - all with a defined structure. 

In a document db application however, one would usually only need a single collection. Collections are schema agnostic, so all your data is usually stored into this one collection - as the document structure doesn't matter. 

If scaling is an issue, there are use cases for using more than one collection.

I'm not that familiar with MongoDB, so terminology / structure might be slightly different there. I was referring to Azure DocumentDB.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think the issue is Mongo API does consider collections similar to tables.  They do have to have a common partition key, so a mix of disparate document types may run into issue when still needing the correct partition key.  Finally due to performance requirements, different document types need different scalability.  A small document type that is queried less frequently needs less RU's than a large document type that is queried frequently.  This would be another reason for not mixing document types.